# Menu Strip from Windows Forms does not have quick properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

in Visual Studio I can not edit my

[image: Menu Strip]

by quick settings.

I've reopened project several times and tried another form, but it doesn't work any case. What do I have to do to show these properties like in

[image: picture 2?]

Comment: Smells like a .NETCore project, best to wait until they are done.

Comment: Hi, I have reproduced this issue. You can report a problem in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to get professional support.